# PHP, how to hash partition by id?

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I need to partition data by id in a limited number of partions, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything in PHP to achieve this.
I have to generate a standard set of values from an integer, for example:

- id 1234 --> hash 0
- id 243  --> hash 1
- id 8471 --> hash 19
- ...

A function that given a number/string, returns randomly a number from 0 to a limit.
In the example above:

- partition_hash(1234, 20) ==> 0
- partition_hash(243, 20) ==> 1
- partition_hash(8471, 20) ==> 19
- ...

How would you solve this problem in PHP?
I thought on using md5, but it gives me a long string that i still need to process to limit the return values.

Thank you.

### UPDATE

And what if instead of integers I have strings?

Comment: Could [Hashids](http://hashids.org/) be useful?

Comment: If you know how many partitions do you want let's say 19, you could use a simple % operator like so:
$partition_nr = $id % 19;
It won't map to your 0, 1, 19 partitions but it will ensure an even distribution between them

Comment: Ok, simple great solution on integers! But what if I have strings as input?